# Get the ".ascx" path of a User Control

Tags: asp.net, web-controls, ascx

Context:

I have created a custom "Script" control that I use in several of my User Controls (these are all loaded via an ASCX path). This Script control provides several interesting features, but I would now like to be able to move the script *out* of the ASCX markup into the same directory as the ASCX control and then load this markup dynamically. (I cannot use normal `<script>` tags because the Script control creates a special binding context such that it can be accessed through a clean API.)

That, currently my Script control is used like (the `<script>` elements inside are consumed by the Script control and should not be confused with the final HTML markup):

```
<SmartScript runat="server">
  <script>/* the code here */</script>
</SmartScript>
```

But I would like it to be usable as:

```
<SmartScript runat="server">
  <script src="~parent/theCode.js" />
</SmartScript>
```

However, I want "~parent" to be expanded to the *filesystem location* of the ASCX control so that I can load the file directly and use that as the contents for the rendered script.

That is, *given the ASCX-based user control (which can be obtained through the Parent property), how is it possible to determine the system path which houses the ASCX markup file?* (And, what caveats should I be aware of?)

Preferably, this would be the complete path as something like `~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/prj/ctrl.ascx"` still leaves another layer of redirect (what does the `~` mean here?) to work through.

(The application runs with enough trust to read from the filesystem, and I am avoiding embedded resources so I can push Layout changes without needing to push the DLLs and restart the IIS workers.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this was ridiculously simple. I imagine it will only be meaningful for controls *with* markup, but it seems to work just fine here.

[`Control.TemplateSourceDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.templatesourcedirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used in conjunction with `Control.MapPathSecure`.

The example from the documentation is:

```
output.Write("The Actual Path of the virtual directory : " + MapPathSecure(TemplateSourceDirectory));
```